# getting grouped day by relational column

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

In my database I have a listings table that has a category_id column, I also have a categories table, each listing can have 1 category, but that category can be shared across any number of listings, this i believe means that it's a 1:n relationship and in my models should be depicted like this,

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = "categories";

    protected $fillable = ['category'];

    public function listings() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
    }
}



    class Listing extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes, HasSlug;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'slug',
            'description',
            'booking_details',
            'cost',
            'active',
            'user_id',
            'category_id',
            'moderated'
        ];
    
    
        protected $appends = [
          'tagsList'
        ];
    
        public function category() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Category');
        }
}
```

What I am wanting to do is get all the listings grouped by their category_id, so I though this would be correct,

```
$cats = Category::with('listings')->get();
```

This returns all the categories, but the listing attributes is null, but I can see listings have matching category_id so they should be getting returned with the categories.

Comment: If there is something you don't understand about my answer, please let me know. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is incorrect. A category can have many listings.

```
public function listings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Listing');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the listings table is holding the category_id field, then you have your relationships set the wrong way around.

Listing should have:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

And Category should have:

```
public function listing() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Listing');
}
```

As stated in the other answer here you also specified a one to many relationship so you should have listing_id on categories table, not category_id on the listings table, then:

Listing should have:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```

And Category should have:

```
public function listing() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
}
```

Furthermore, if a category doesn't actually belong to a listing, you will need a pivot table called category_listing, with listing_id, category_id, and you will have the following relationships.

Listing should have:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

And Category should have:

```
public function listing() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Listing');
}
```